# How can I combine/split properties with AutoMapper?

Tags: automapper

we're using Automapper (http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to map between entities and dto's. We have a situation where one property on an entity corresponds to three different properties on the dto, and we need to write some custom logic to do the mapping. Anyone know how we can do that? (We need to map both ways, from entity and from dto).

I notice that AutoMapper supports custom resolvers to do custom mapping logic, but as far as I can tell from the documentation, they only allow you to map a single property to another single property.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [custom type converter](http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Type%20Converters).  It allows you to define a converter for an entire type, not just a single property.